# Angularjs up/down spin button not working In IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In Chrome it's working fine but same functionality not working in IE11. My html code is

```
<div ng-switch="row.type">
 <input ng-switch-when="Increment" type="number" min="{{row.minVal}}" max="{{row.maxVal}}" step="{{row.step}}" ng-model="dynamicVal[row.name]" required class="form-control">
 <select ng-switch-when="LookUp" class="form-control" ng-model="dynamicVal[row.name]" ng-change="selectedLookUp(row.name, row.isAjax)" >
   <option ng-repeat="lookup in row.lookUpValues" value="{{lookup.id}}">{{lookup.name}}</option>
  </select>
<input ng-switch-default type="number" min="{{row.minVal}}" max="{{row.maxVal}}" step="{{row.step}}" ng-model="dynamicVal[row.name]" required class="form-control">
 </div>
```

and CSS is this

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  

   opacity: 1;
}
```

I am new to CSS.

Comment: webkit wont target for IE

Answer (score 1):

[It's meant to only work in Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button). There is no way to do what you are asking. Quoting MSDN's documentation on `::-webkit-inner-spin-button`:

> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. **Do not** use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

And

> **Specifications**
>
> **NOT** part of any specification. This is a **proprietary** pseudo-element **specific** to WebKit/Blink.

You can see it's clearly only supported by Webkit based browsers like Chrome, Opera and Safari (Internet Explorer isn't Webkit based):
[image]

Comment: I already told you it cant be solved. I suggest you mark this as correct answer since there is no solution to your problem. Otherwise we're going to have to close this question as to not confuse other users into thinking this doesnt have an answer yet.